# Return multiple column headers based on the color of the cells within a row

Tags: excel, vba

My data sheet ("srData") is a pivot table that is filled using a userform. All data have a unique ID in column A of the data sheet.
In the userform checkboxes are selected, which will change the cells, in columns K:AA, interior color to white(2), else interior color is grey(15)
[image: Image of Worksheet srData]

What I need to be able to do, is on another sheet ("Formulier"), based on the value of a drop down box (C6)where the unique ID is selected (i.e. SR-1, SR-2,SR-3 etc...), perform a lookup against the table to return the headers where the interior color of the Cell is colorindex=2. The results of this lookup need to be place on sheet("Formulier") in column A starting from row 19 down to row 28. No more then 10 rows will be filled based on the checkboxes.

For example, based on the table above, If SR-2 was selected from the drop down then the headers returned should be placed in column A, row 19= pH, row 20= NO2-IC
[image: Image of worksheet Formulier with SR-2 selected]

And if SR-4 is selected from drop down then the headers returned should be placed in column A, row 19= OBD, row 20= F-CFA, row 21=NO3-CFA, row 22= NO2-CFA
[image: Image of worksheet Formulier with SR-4 selected]

I have tried the code using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908276/i-need-to-return-multiple-column-headers-from-a-table-based-on-the-value-of-the) but this is not exactly what I am looking for. As this code places the headers allin on cell, and it is based on a value and not a color.

I hope someone is able to help me.

Comment: Colors have a value.  You can test a cell by checking it's background color, for example Cells(1,1).interior.color=rgb(121,121,121)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Color Search

### In a Standard Module (Go to VBE >> Insert >> Module)

```
Option Explicit

Public Const CriteriaCell As String = "C6"    ' Criteria Cell Range Address

Sub ColorSearch()

    ' Source
    Const cSource As Variant = "srData"       ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cCriteriaColumn As Variant = "A"    ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
    Const cColumns As String = "K:AA"         ' Columns Range Address
    Const cHeaderRow As Long = 1              ' Header Row Number
    Const cColorIndex As Long = 2             ' Criteria Color Index (2-White)
    ' Target
    Const cTarget As Variant = "Formulier"    ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cFr As Long = 19                    ' First Row Number
    Const cCol As Variant = "A"               ' Column Letter/Number

    Dim rng As Range      ' Source Found Cell Range
    Dim vntH As Variant   ' Header Array
    Dim vntC As Variant   ' Color Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Source/Color Array Column Counter
    Dim k As Long         ' Target Array Row Counter
    Dim sRow As Long      ' Color Row
    Dim SVal As String    ' Search Value
    Dim Noe As Long       ' Source Number of Elements

    ' Write value from Criteria Cell Range to Search Value.
    SVal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget).Range(CriteriaCell)

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource)
        ' Search for Search Value in Source Criteria Column and create
        ' a reference to Source Found Cell Range.
        Set rng = .Columns(cCriteriaColumn) _
                .Find(SVal, , xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext)
        ' Check if Search Value not found. Exit if.
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        ' Write row of Source Found Cell Range to Color Row.
        sRow = rng.Row
        ' Release rng variable (not needed anymore).
        Set rng = Nothing
        ' In Source Columns
        With .Columns(cColumns)
            ' Copy Header Range to Header Array.
            vntH = .Rows(cHeaderRow)
            ' Copy Color Range to Color Array.
            vntC = .Rows(sRow)
            ' Write number of columns in Source Columns to Source Number
            ' of Elements.
            Noe = .Columns.Count
            ' Loop through columns of Color Range/Array.
            For i = 1 To Noe
                ' Write current ColorIndex of Color Range to current
                ' element in Color Array.
                vntC(1, i) = .Cells(sRow, i).Interior.ColorIndex
            Next
        End With
    End With
    ' Resize Target Array to Number of Elements rows and one column.
    ReDim vntT(1 To Noe, 1 To 1)
    ' Loop through columns of Color Array.
    For i = 1 To Noe
        ' Check if current value in Color Array is equal to Criteria
        ' Column Index.
        If vntC(1, i) = cColorIndex Then
            ' Count row in Target Array.
            k = k + 1
            ' Write value of current COLUMN in Header Array to
            ' element in current ROW of Target Array.
            vntT(k, 1) = vntH(1, i)
        End If
    Next

    ' Erase Header and Color Arrays (not needed anymore).
    Erase vntH
    Erase vntC

    ' In Target Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget)
        ' Calculate Target Range by resizing the cell at the intersection of
        ' Target First Row and Target Column, by Number of Elements.
        ' Copy Target Array to Target Range.
        .Cells(cFr, cCol).Resize(Noe) = vntT
    End With

End Sub
```

### In Worksheet Formulier (In VBE double-click Formulier)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range(CriteriaCell)) Is Nothing Then
            ColorSearch
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

### White Cell Values Version

- Added writing the values of white cells to D column of worksheet
  `Formulier`.
- *** indicates what had to be added.
- Change `ColorSearch2` to `ColorSearch`.

```vb
Sub ColorSearch2()

    ' Source
    Const cSource As Variant = "srData"       ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cCriteriaColumn As Variant = "A"    ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
    Const cColumns As String = "K:AA"         ' Columns Range Address
    Const cHeaderRow As Long = 1              ' Header Row Number
    Const cColorIndex As Long = 2             ' Criteria Color Index (2-White)
    ' Target
    Const cTarget As Variant = "Formulier"    ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cFr As Long = 19                    ' First Row Number
    Const cCol As Variant = "A"               ' Column Letter/Number
    Const cColVal As Variant = "D"            ' *** Value Column Letter/Number

    Dim rng As Range      ' Source Found Cell Range
    Dim vntH As Variant   ' Header Array
    Dim vntC As Variant   ' Color Array
    Dim vntV As Variant   ' *** Value Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim vntTV As Variant  ' *** Target Value Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Source/Color Array Column Counter
    Dim k As Long         ' Target Array Row Counter
    Dim sRow As Long      ' Color Row
    Dim SVal As String    ' Search Value
    Dim Noe As Long       ' Source Number of Elements

    ' Write value from Criteria Cell Range to Search Value.
    SVal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget).Range(CriteriaCell)

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource)
        ' Search for Search Value in Source Criteria Column and create
        ' a reference to Source Found Cell Range.
        Set rng = .Columns(cCriteriaColumn) _
                .Find(SVal, , xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext)
        ' Check if Search Value not found. Exit if.
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        ' Write row of Source Found Cell Range to Color Row.
        sRow = rng.Row
        ' Release rng variable (not needed anymore).
        Set rng = Nothing
        ' In Source Columns
        With .Columns(cColumns)
            ' Copy Header Range to Header Array.
            vntH = .Rows(cHeaderRow)
            ' Copy Color Range to Color Array.
            vntC = .Rows(sRow)
            ' *** Copy Color Range to Value Array.
            ' Note: The values are also written to Color Array, but are
            '       later overwritten with the Color Indexes.
            vntV = .Rows(sRow)
            ' Write number of columns in Source Columns to Source Number
            ' of Elements.
            Noe = .Columns.Count
            ' Loop through columns of Color Range/Array.
            For i = 1 To Noe
                ' Write current ColorIndex of Color Range to current
                ' element in Color Array.
                vntC(1, i) = .Cells(sRow, i).Interior.ColorIndex
            Next
        End With
    End With
    ' Resize Target Array to Number of Elements rows and one column.
    ReDim vntT(1 To Noe, 1 To 1)
    ' *** Resize Target Value Array to Number of Elements rows and one column.
    ReDim vntTV(1 To Noe, 1 To 1)
    ' Loop through columns of Color Array.
    For i = 1 To Noe
        ' Check if current value in Color Array is equal to Criteria
        ' Column Index.
        If vntC(1, i) = cColorIndex Then
            ' Count row in Target Array.
            k = k + 1
            ' Write value of current COLUMN in Header Array to
            ' element in current ROW of Target Array.
            vntT(k, 1) = vntH(1, i)
            ' *** Write value of current COLUMN in Value Array to
            ' element in current ROW of Target Value Array.
            vntTV(k, 1) = vntV(1, i)
        End If
    Next

    ' Erase Header and Color Arrays (not needed anymore).
    Erase vntH
    Erase vntC
    Erase vntV '***

    ' In Target Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget)
        ' Calculate Target Range by resizing the cell at the intersection of
        ' Target First Row and Target Column, by Number of Elements.
        ' Copy Target Array to Target Range.
        .Cells(cFr, cCol).Resize(Noe) = vntT
        ' *** Calculate Target Value Range by resizing the cell at the
        ' intersection of Target First Row and Value Column, by Number of
        ' Elements.
        ' Copy Target Value Array to Target Value Range.
        .Cells(cFr, cColVal).Resize(Noe) = vntTV
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This works exactly like I needed. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I do have one more question and if I have to use a new question for this please let me know. I would like to know if in this sub it is also possible to return the value in the white cells once it has been entered? The value wil allways be a number and must go in column D of "Formulier". If it is beter to make a new sub, I will give it a try. If I overstept my bounds by asking this my apologies.

Comment: @Bellandra: Added the White Cell Values Version.

Comment: Thanks so much for the very quick answer. Will look at it in a hour, I have a appointment.

Comment: It works beautifully. Can't thank you enough! Also very nice that you explained what code does, this way I can learn more about this. Trying to solve this problem has taken me weeks of searching.

Comment: @Bellandra: I'm glad I could have helped you. I must say that you have asked your questions flawlessly to every last detail which is the reason I answered your 'Bonus' question with a smile on my face. Well done.